# How do i know if the word is step or glide in English

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality, pronunciation, questions

today I have a lesson in school about steps and glides and i didn't understand it.

My first question what are steps and glides?
My second  question is how do i know if the sentence ends with steps or glide?

Here are some example

> she is friendly and outgoing.

the sentence ends with *outgoing* is it steps or glide  and how do i know if it is steps or glide?

the second example

> He is quiet and shy.

The word ends with *shy* is it steps or glide and how do i know if it is steps  or glide?

Comment: Hmmm, as a native speaker of English I have no idea what steps and glides are in this context.  I’m not hopeful that you knowing will help you learn English either.

Comment: Your first question is one we should be asking you, I fear. What _are_ steps and glides? As far as I know, they are movements that you make with your feet—not things that you can end sentences with. If you didn’t understand what they were in class, you should ask your teacher.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet steps are also elements of a stair.

Comment: @phoog Yes, and many other things beside—but foot movement is the only context I can think of where something can be either a step or a glide. I thought first about glide vowels when I read the question, but I have no idea what _step_ would be, then, and it doesn't really seem to fit the examples given either.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I thought the same.  Then I did a little search.  See my answer.

Comment: @Jim see my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.pronunciationtips.com/syllables2.htm, steps and glides describe the nature of pitch changes in a sentence, for example, the falling tone at the end of a declaration.  The rule, which I evaluate as a native speaker and it seems entirely plausible, is that at the end of a sentence, the pitch glides downward if the last word is a single syllable or is a multisyllabic word with stress on the final syllable.  The pitch steps down when the stress is on a syllable other than the last.

In your examples, *shy* is a one-syllable word, and *outgoing* is a three-syllable word with stress on the first or second syllable (see comments).  Therefore, *shy* is a glide and *outgoing* is a step.

Comment: Great answer, except that I would stress the first syllable of *outgoing*.

Comment: @PeterShor you have filled me with self doubt.  I would certainly stress the first syllable if the meaning were "the opposite of incoming" but I could go both ways with this sense.  It doesn't affect the analysis of glides and steps, though.  I will edit.

Answer (score -1):

Just a guess, but it sounds like your teacher is trying to describe some aspect of how English "flows".

> "He is quiet and shy"

has short step-like syllables while

> "She is friendly and outgoing"

*seems* to run more smoothly together to my ears (gliding) - but I have no idea how this would be useful except for poetry.

---

I do not recognize the terms "steps" and "glide" in an English learning sense. If no better answers appear you may have to ask your teacher for clarification. (and that is what they are there for!)